# Sorting on nested Id property

Tags: ravendb

Let's say we have a document like this

```
public class Event
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public EntityDescriptor Venue { get; set; }

    // Other properties omitted for simplicity
}

public class EntityDescriptor
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And an index like this

```
public class Events : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Event>
{
    public Events()
    {
        Map = items => from e in items
                       select new
                       {
                           Venue_Id = e.Venue.Id,
                           Venue_Name = e.Venue.Name
                       };
    }
}
```

When trying to sort on `Event.Venue.Id`

```
session.Query<Event, Events>().Take(10).OrderBy(e => e.Venue.Id).ToArray();
```

the sent request is

/indexes/Events?&pageSize=10&`sort=__document_id`&SortHint-__document_id=String

Is this by design or a bug?

PS: `OrderBy(e => e.Venue.Name)` works as expected (`sort=Venue_Name`).

Comment: If you look at the index inside Raven Studio, what does it look like?

Comment: It's like this (as expected): `docs.Events.Select(e => new { Venue_Id = e.Venue.Id, Venue_Name = e.Venue.Name })` (sorry for the formatting but it's limited inside comments). If I don't create static index, the auto index is like this `from doc in docs.Events
select new {
 __document_id = doc.__document_id
}` That's why I think it's a bug.

Comment: Agreed this appears to be a bug. I recommend you submit a simple repro case to the Raven Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ravendb

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. __document_id is the special known field containing the ID of the document. It's there regardless of whether you have an .Id property.

*edit*

I misread your question. This indeed appears to be a bug. I recommend you send a simple repro case to the [Raven forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ravendb) and let them know which RavenDB version you're using.

Comment: I'm aware of the purpose of `__document_id` (and `DocumentConvention.FindIdentityProperty`). Please pay attention to the example. We need to sort by the Id property of a nested object (`Event.Venue.Id`), not the document Id itself (`Event.Id`). So the generated HTTP request is not what we want and we don't get the desired results.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see you were trying to sort by a nested ID.